# Replacing <form> Tag in HTML

Tags: html, forms, tags

I have created a button in which whenever I will click it will directly send mail to the contact from my outlook. I am using form tag to perform this task. My code is given below:

```
 <p><form action="mailto:abc@google.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain"><button class="button" a href="mailto:abc@google.com">Contact</button></form></p>
```

But unfortunately some other flatform(Like Share-point etc)are not allowing this form tag as they don't support  tag.How to replace this form tag with some other tag which helps to perfrom the same task.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use an `anchor`-element `<a>` like this:

```html
<a href="mailto:abc@google.com">Contact</a>
```

This makes both the button and the form obsolete.

Comment: I tried with <button class="button" a href="mailto:abc@google.com">Contact</button></a> but its not working

Comment: You don't need the button tag.  Just the <a href="mailto:abc@google.com">Contact</a>